# JBoss EAP 6 - Change Password Vault Password

Tags: jboss, passwords

we need to be able to update the JBoss password vault password to comply with periodic password rotation security requirements.  We must deal w/ this older JBoss vault for now.  I can manipulate the constituent keystore pwd (which I believe is the vault pwd) and can prob remask that/store it back in "standalone-full.xml".  Wondering what the best practice is tho, or if there's a better - or (JBoss) prescribed - way to do this.

Thx!

Comment: Not sure this can be done w/out knowing the existing pwd, and if in a emergency recovery situation, looks like the only thing that will help is creating a new vault.  So I guess that?"  Can't find anything on that anywhere.

Comment: 1 thought I had, was to simply create another vault and reload it (we know what keystore pwds were stored in there initially).  Importing it in requires the old pwd.

Comment: Facilitating my "create new/transfer/delete old/rename new" plan to simulate the keystore pwd reset, the java "keytool" utility allows for importing of 1 keystore to another - with only the destination (new) password; it groans about not having the old keystore pwd, but seems to perform the import w/ warnings.  However, at least the Windows 1.7/7 JDK ver seems to only work for JKS types. 
 For JCEKS (what I need), behavior is sporadic (works sometimes).  Often rearranging "java.security" providers helps so played w/ the Sun/SunJCE provider order, but no combo has worked yet.

Comment: Turns out my keystore-->keystore xfer ("keytool" "-importkeystore") problem is the inability to export anything "secret" (symmetric key, assym private key) w/out the source store/key pwds; makes sense, search continues.